# Can one constructor take care of multiple types of different object parameters?

Tags: c++

Can one constructor take care of multiple objects?

For example:

A constructor from `class Add` has a `constructor Add(Mult m1, Div d1)` but also has another constructor takes the parameters `Add(Div d2, Mult m2)`, is there any way I could create one constructor, that can decide which parameters the user entered and run based on that?

If not I have multiple objects which would cause me to make more than 20 constructors?

The job is basically the same for both constructors which is to add the object types. In C++.

Comment: Might be better to have two constructors and [delegate one constructor to the other](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor) with the parameters flipped.

Comment: `template` seems the solution, possibly to the constructor or maybe to the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Type level

Well, if you can use C++11, use can use forwarding references for that and dispatch them, similar to this:

```
class A {
public:
  template<class _First, class _Second>
  A(_First&& firstArgument, _Second&& secondArgument);
};
```

Inside the constructor you then may use functionality of the `<type_traits>` header to distinguish between types an call appropriate methods.

Before C++11 however, you can still do a similar thing (probably hardcoded for const l-value references) but you will likely have to code many things yourself.

### Polymorphism

Another quite common solution to this thing would be to create a superclass e.g. `SimpleExpression` where your classes inherit from and then just take the base class type.

Comment: Or use [delegating constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Delegating_constructor).

Comment: This is another option, however this still will result in many constructors while OP is trying to manage this task with a single constructor.

Comment: *"distinguish between types an call appropriate methods"* C++17 might be required for its `if constexpr`.

Comment: Forwarding references seems not needed, as const ref seems enough, and then `std::is_same` can be implemented prior C++11.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, that's what the last paragraph before the second headline was suggesting. If this fits your needs, take it.